# Can't fetch data from http server in release mode react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api

I tried to fetch the api from 'http://12.129.302.253:9005', it work fine in debug mode.When I bundle release, apis are not callabl.Any solution please.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like it.. Make sure you have added the following settings

For Android in `AndroidManifest.xml` add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and for iOS in `info.plist` add this

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key><YOUR DOMAIN eg: google.com ></key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

It should work for both.

Comment: Thaks for the answer ,API works well in debug mode, when I build and release, apis are not callable. Internet permission is already included as default .